# centos 7 on virtualbox has no directories

Tags: virtualbox, centos7

[as shown here: after  installing centos iso on VirtualBox, I use ls to see directory there is None](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28C1b.jpg)
I tried to install many iso but they all ended up with no directory like shown in the screenshot. Can someone help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you appear in root directory.

```
cd /
ls
```